# TypeRocket - Conditional fields

Tags: wordpress, typerocket

I've got a Typerocket form (within Wordpress) and I'm trying to make a conditional field.

Like if the Type field is Image, show and Image field afterwards and if the Type field is Quote have a text (editor) field afterwards.

I can't find anything about Conditional fields in Typerocket's doc.

Here's what I got right now.

```
echo $form->repeater('pj_images_du_projet')->setLabel("Images du projet")->setFields([
        $form->select('Type')->setOptions([
            "Image"=>'image',
            "Vidéo"=>'video',
            "Témoignage"=>'temoignage'
        ]), //Type is what chooses what fields are below. Options are Image, Video or Testimonial
        $form->image('image')->setLabel('Image'), //image only
        $form->text('video')->setLabel('Vidéo'), //video only
        $form->toggle('autoplay')->setLabel('Autoplay'), //video only
        $form->textarea('temoignage')->setLabel('Témoignage'), //temoignage only
        $form->text('auteur')->setLabel('Auteur'), //temoignage only
    ]);
```

Comment: TypeRocket does not have conditional fields but the pro version coming out in the next few weeks will have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a JS that does the work.

JS

```
jQuery('body').ready(function(){
    jQuery("body").on('change','.is-conditional-selector',function(){px_redoConditionals();})
    px_redoConditionals();
})

function px_redoConditionals(){
    jQuery('body').find('.is-conditional-selector').each(function(){
        var repeater = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent();
        console.log(repeater.attr('class'));
        repeater.find('.is-conditional').removeClass('px-show');
        //console.log(jQuery(this).val());
        repeater.find('.is-conditional.is-conditional-'+jQuery(this).val()).addClass('px-show');
    })
}
```

CSS

```
.is-conditional:not(.px-show){
    display:none !important;
}
```

And then I add this to the select that changes which section is shown

```
->setAttribute('class','is-conditional-selector')
```

And this on the fields that need to be shown or hidden

```
->setAttribute('class','is-conditional is-conditional-[value of the select to show this]'),
```